# Найти максимальное сходство массивов

Tags: javascript

Есть json:

```
var all = [{
    'id' : 1,
    'x' : 3,
    'y' : 1.5,
    z : 1.5,
    ves : 100,
    v : 0.15,
    'norma' : 'до 15',
    money : 0,
    'money_holiday' : 100,
    wait : 100,
    dostavka_time : 500,
    dostavka_nighttime : 1000,
    dostavka_fixnighttime : 1500
}, {
    'id' : 2,
    'x' : 3,
    'y' : 1.7,
    z : 1.6,
    ves : 50,
    v : 0.15,
    'norma' : 'до 15',
    money : 300,
    'money_holiday' : 300,
    wait : 100,
    dostavka_time : 500,
    dostavka_nighttime : 1000,
    dostavka_fixnighttime : 1500
}, {
    'id' : 3,
    'x' : 3,
    'y' : 1.7,
    z : 1.6,
    ves : 100,
    v : 0.4,
    'norma' : 'до 15',
    money : 300,
    'money_holiday' : 300,
    wait : 100,
    dostavka_time : 500,
    dostavka_nighttime : 1000,
    dostavka_fixnighttime : 1500
}];
```

Как в нем найти сходство с

```
    {'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50}
```

?

т.е. нужно поэлементно сравнивать с исходным массивом и найти первое попавшееся

Т.е.

`{ 'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7 }` вернет 2 элемента

`{ 'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6 }` тоже 2

а  `{ 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50 }`  один

Comment: что значит сходство ?? покажите какой должен быть вывод

Comment: Нашёл. `i=1`. Всё?

Comment: Для каждого объекта посчитать дельты между его полями и полями эталона . Вероятно, пронормировать дельты относительно значений полей эталона (|x-x0| / x0 ). Вычислить взвешенную сумму этих нормирвоанных дельт, получив некий ранг. Осортировать объекты по возрастанию ранга.

Comment: @Nofate, вряд ли. Подозреваю, что речь идёт о точном соответствии.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мы тут все со своими хрустальными шарами набежали ) я пытался сделать задачу интересной )

Comment: Если найти только один первый попавшийся, то можно перебрать элементы массива и сравнить с шаблоном, например так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392741/best-way-to-get-intersection-of-keys-of-two-objects

Comment: @des1roer  что вы имеете в виду говоря элемент? и id элемент и objct элемент.Лучше напишите какой результат вы ожидаете

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь [Массив: перебирающие методы -> filter](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#filter)

```js
  
 
var all = [
    {'id': 1, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.5, z: 1.5, ves: 100, v: 0.15, 'norma': 'до 15',
      money: 0, 'money_holiday': 100, wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500,
      dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500},
    {'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50, v: 0.15, 'norma': 'до 15',
      money: 300, 'money_holiday': 300, wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500,
      dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500},
    {'id': 3, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 100, v: 0.4, 'norma': 'до 15',
      money: 300, 'money_holiday': 300, wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500,
      dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500}
];

var pattern = {'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50} ;

var result = all.filter( function(val,key) {
if ( val.x == pattern.x && val.y == pattern.y && val.z == pattern.z && val.ves == pattern.ves )
    return val;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: По скольку вопрос размыт и по моему в вопросе есть логическая ошибка,то привожу пример с точным совпадением пока не будет ясно.
Но все равно вся логика творится в callback переданный в filter

Answer (score 1):

> т.е. нужно поэлементно сравнивать с исходным массивом и найти первое попавшееся
>
> т.е.
>
> {'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7 вернет 2 элемента
>
> {'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, тоже 2
>
> а  {'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50}  один

Не понятен критерий "подобия" (примеры противоречат заголовки вопроса)...

Набросал несколько вариантов (можно записать короче, но это вы сами):

```js
 
(function(){
"use strict";

var all = [
    {'id': 1, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.5, z: 1.5, ves: 100, v: 0.15, 'norma': 'до 15',
      money: 0, 'money_holiday': 100, wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500,
      dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500},
    {'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50, v: 0.15, 'norma': 'до 15',
      money: 300, 'money_holiday': 300, wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500,
      dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500},
    {'id': 3, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 100, v: 0.4, 'norma': 'до 15',
      money: 300, 'money_holiday': 300, wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500,
      dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500}
];

var pattern = {'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50};

var similarity = function ( arrs, pattern, isUseVal ) {
    var keys = Object.keys( pattern ),
        count = keys.length,
        result = [],
        arr,
        key,
        j;

    for ( var i = 0, l = arrs.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        arr = arrs[i],
        result[i] = 0;
        for ( j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
            if ( isUseVal ) {
                result[i] += ( ( key = keys[j]) in arr ) && ( arr[key] == pattern[key] );
            } else {
                result[i] += ( ( key = keys[j]) in arr );
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};

var similarity2 = function ( arrs, pattern ) {
    var keys = Object.keys( pattern ),
        count = keys.length,
        result = 0,
        similarity,
        arr,
        key,
        j;

    for ( var i = 0, l = arrs.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        similarity = 0,
        arr = arrs[i];
        for ( j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
            similarity += ( ( key = keys[j]) in arr ) && ( arr[key] == pattern[key] );
        }
        result += similarity == count;
    }
    return result;
};

console.log( similarity( all, pattern, !0 ) );
console.log( similarity( all, pattern, !1 ) );
console.log( similarity2( all, pattern ) );

})();
```

1. Результат подобных элементов (и значений) шаблона в переданных массивах.
2. Результат подобных элементов (без значений) шаблона в переданных массивах.
3. Количество подобных шаблону массивов среди переданных.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно пальцем в небо, т.к. либо вы ошиблись со значениями в примерах, либо вам нужен какой-то неточный поиск.

Если нужно найти только те объекты в массиве, которые точно равны критерию, без учета отсутствующих полей, можно воспользоваться [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```js
var all = [{
  'id' : 1,
  'x' : 3,
  'y' : 1.5,
  z : 1.5,
  ves : 100,
  v : 0.15,
  'norma' : 'до 15',
  money : 0,
  'money_holiday' : 100,
  wait : 100,
  dostavka_time : 500,
  dostavka_nighttime : 1000,
  dostavka_fixnighttime : 1500
 }, {
  'id' : 2,
  'x' : 3,
  'y' : 1.7,
  z : 1.6,
  ves : 50,
  v : 0.15,
  'norma' : 'до 15',
  money : 300,
  'money_holiday' : 300,
  wait : 100,
  dostavka_time : 500,
  dostavka_nighttime : 1000,
  dostavka_fixnighttime : 1500
 }, {
  'id' : 3,
  'x' : 3,
  'y' : 1.7,
  z : 1.6,
  ves : 100,
  v : 0.4,
  'norma' : 'до 15',
  money : 300,
  'money_holiday' : 300,
  wait : 100,
  dostavka_time : 500,
  dostavka_nighttime : 1000,
  dostavka_fixnighttime : 1500
 }
];


console.log(_.filter(all, { 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7 }).length);
console.log(_.filter(all, { 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6 }).length);
console.log(_.filter(all, { 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50 }).length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Пример рабочий, выводит так, как вы хотели (2, 2, 1). Но пришлось немного подправить условия чтобы ответ сошелся. А именно убрать `'id': 2`, т.к. не понятно почему должны находиться два объекта, если в исходном массиве только один с таким `id`.

Comment: Велосипеды - не ваш метод ?

Comment: @t1nk только если для души )